# create-react-app: jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js cannot found tweenlite.js

Tags: webpack, jquery-plugins, require, create-react-app

I am building a react application created with create-react-app. I am facing some difficulties in using the jquery plugin jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js.

First of all, I placed this library in the `src/assets` folder so it can be accessible by webpack. Then in my index.tsx file, I require it this way:

> require("./assets/plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js");

Then I get this error:

> ./src/assets/plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'TweenLite' in
>   'C:\projects\schoolz\src\assets\plugins\rs-plugin\js'

I verified that the tweenlite.js file is really in the folder though.

[image]

Delving inside the source code of jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js, I can see that a call is made to require the tweenlite.js:

[image]

This call fails. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your Webpack configuration file:

```
resolve: {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname),
  extensions: ['', '.js'],
  alias: {
    "TweenLite": "gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite" //Path to your TweenLite file
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I have created this app with "create-react-app" (typescript). I do not have access to the webconfig.json unless I eject

Comment: Did you find some answer ? I have the same error :(